# Git has huge performance issues on windows

Tags: windows, performance, git, mercurial

I always knew Git ran better on POSIX compliant systems. However, since I recently joined a windows development team for the first time I'm having my first real life experience with a large Git repository on windows (7).

To make a long story short the performance is horrible and is a huge productivity issue.
The repository around 4 GB and uses lots of submodules (which seems to be the slow part). Here are some average benchmarks done on several windows and mac/linux machines.

```
$ time git checkout NameOfBranch => win: 3.1s, mac/linux => 0.1s

$ time git submodule sync => win: 1m16s, mac/linux => 1.1s

$ time git submodule update --init --recursive => win: 1m33s, mac/linux => 2.1s
```

Converting from Git is not an option, but apart from that I'm pretty open to various solutions. Obviously I would prefer if someone had a local solution but from Google this seems to be a fundamental limitation in the way NTFS works.

Maybe it would be possible to host a server running Mercurial (on Linux) as a proxy for the real Git repository. I have no idea if this is a practical solution, but I'm getting pretty desperate since stashing, committing, etc is horrible slow.

Any input is appreciated

Comment: Have you considered/tried using a VM? I personally use one on my mac, where I use git and similar tools and then access the files from a windows VM (it is set as a shared folder, so I don't even need to copy files). Maybe a similar setup might work for you?

Comment: That sounds indeed like a bug in git's submodule implementation. Have you tried to contact the appropriate maintainers about this issue? I'm not sure if I understand what you think Mercurial can do in this case for you (as a proxy), though.

Comment: Use a libgit2 implementation.

Comment: There's only so much you can do on Windows, given it's limited file creation performance (see http://www.bitsnbites.eu/benchmarking-os-primitives/ ). It will be interesting to see what comes out of the optimizations from Microsoft: https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2017/05/90-of-windows-devs-now-using-git-creating-1760-windows-builds-per-day/